# terraform for_each index for NAT GW with multiple subnets

Tags: terraform

I need to setup multiple private subnets at AWS per account and **I need to have only one NAT GW per Account** and traffic routed to this. The problem I guess is that the values are a map without an index. As I remember with count you have an index which can be simply accessed *subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private[0].id* But I can't change the current setup. I need to create an idnex out of this map.

I have a yaml file with this values:

```
aws:
  - accounts: ciss-goesaws-test
    private_subnets:
      -
        az: eu-central-1a
        short: a
        cidr: 10.44.4.96/27
      -
        az: eu-central-1b
        short: b
        cidr: 10.44.5.128/27
      -
        az: eu-central-1c
        short: c
        cidr: 10.44.6.160/27
```

I have the following terraform code. But this creates one NAT GW per subnet. ***I need to NAT GW to be created in only one of the subnets.***

```
locals {
  private = flatten([
    for a in var.aws : [
      for ps in a.private_subnets : {
        accounts = a.accounts
        az = ps.az
        cidr = ps.cidr
        short = ps.short
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_eip" "this" {
  vpc = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "this" {
  for_each = {
    for cidr_block in local.private : cidr_block.cidr => cidr_block
  }
  allocation_id = aws_eip.this.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private[each.key].id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each = {
    for cidr_block in local.private : cidr_block.cidr => cidr_block
  }

  availability_zone = each.value.az
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.this.id
  tags              = {
    Name = "${each.value.accounts}-private-${each.value.short}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  for_each = {
    for cidr_block in local.private : cidr_block.cidr => cidr_block
  }

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.this.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.this[each.key].id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  for_each = {
    for cidr_block in local.private : cidr_block.cidr => cidr_block
  }

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private[each.key].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[each.key].id
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a single NAT gateway placed in multiple subnets. I am unsure if this would be allowed in AWS.

Comment: I need one NAT GW in a public subnet and then route everything from the private networks to it. I did it in the past with count where I can access the index. But with the for_each approach I don't have this. I need a solution with for_each.

Answer (score 0):

As the CIDRs are used as index for the subnet resource collection, you have to select one (maybe first) for the NAT GW.

For example:

```
locals {
  nat_gw_subnet_cidr = var.aws[0].private_subnets[0].cidr
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "this" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.this.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private[local.nat_gw_subnet_cidr].id
}

# `aws_subnet` resource as in the question

# One route table should be enough, as all subnets share the same GW
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.this.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.this.id
  }
  # No route for the VPC?
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  # Simpler to use the subnets as index
  for_each = aws_subnet.private

  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private.id
}
```